# I am puzzled by php's bcadd bad math. Outputs wrong results

Tags: php

Can someone tell me a workaround or if there is a solution to the following rounding error in PHP?

The correct answer is 0, instead, it returns 0.00000886.

```
$number1 = 0.2;
$number2 = 0.11740149;
$number3 = -0.00298845;
$number4 = -0.31440418;
$number5 = -0.00000886;

$total_bc = bcadd(bcadd(bcadd(bcadd($number1, $number2,8) ,$number3,8),$number4,8),$number5,8);
echo "Totalbc sum: ".$total_bc.""; //should be 0, gives 0.00000886
```

Also tried Decimal.io library at https://php-decimal.io with the same result.

Comment: [Because that really is the sum](https://3v4l.org/mciUG). I combined positive and negative values and they are *not* identical

Comment: @JohnConde, edited the question. it was missing one input. still gives the wrong answer. thx.

Comment: Warning: bcadd(): bcmath function argument is not well-formed in /in/IfGWe on line 9

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde, numbers were not converted to string. Problem solved.